# samsung j7 showing process is not responding?

Tags: rooting, samsung

after using link2sd app to move app to sdcard while moving the app, my mobile got restarted and then it shows process is not responding error, and i can't access images, my mobile not showing any files and it can't recognize sdcard, and my mobile is rooted.
please help

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Link2SD, on the left top corner, press the triple line, and look in the list for "revert SD card changes"

Alternatively try booting into safe mode using the right hardware key combination for your device.

For your Device Model it would be:

1. Turn the device off.
2. Press and hold the Power key past the screen with the device name.
3. When 'SAMSUNG' appears on the screen, release the Power key.
4. Immediately after releasing the Power key, press and hold the Volume down key.
5. Continue to hold the Volume down key until the device finishes restarting.
6. Safe mode will display in the bottom left corner of the screen.
7. Release the Volume down key when you see 'Safe Mode'.

Comment: I have tried booting in safe mode but i doesn't work, i don't have access to mobile storage it shows storage/emulated/0 not found and system apps aren't working like camera and the apps which i moved to sdcard aren't working .